# Jquery If, Else Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have spent last 2 days working on a front page to a new website but these one functionality I cant get to work.

It's probably best to view this link.

http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~stagedgo/html/

When you hover on promotions the page pushes 20px to the left, but when the slider is pushed clicked, when you hover over it again it should push 20 px to the right.

I used the code bellow, the way it works it checks if the wrapper has been pushed.

```
if ($('.wrapper').css('marginLeft') ==  "0px") {
          //code to push page left 20
     }
 if ($('.wrapper').css('marginLeft') >  "1px") {
          //code to push page right 20
     }
```

Any help would be amazing, thanks.

Comment: Don't compare strings, but parse the pixels to numbers

Comment: What do you mean? Could you elaborate please

Comment: `"10px > "1px"` is `false`. Use `parseInt(margin, 10) > 1` instead

Comment: Sorry to ask again, im very new to jquery could you explain this more clearly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, it's plain Javascript. Comparing strings against each other is done lexically, not numerically, with the shown results.

Comment: "10px" is a string, and jQuery won't be able to run maths functions against it. Instead you have to turn that "10px" into an Integer (i.e. 10). Thats why you need to use `parseInt()` as it will turn string("10") to int(10).

Comment: oh ok i tried eugene method but this has not worked.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the "more than" operator on something that is not a number.

Try this:

```
if ($('.wrapper').css('marginLeft') ==  "0px") {
      //code to push page left 20
} else {
      //code to push page right 20
}
```

Alternatively, you can just pass the numbers without "px" to compare:

```
if (parseInt($('.wrapper').css('marginLeft')) ==  0) {
      //code to push page left 20
}
if (parseInt($('.wrapper').css('marginLeft')) >=  20) {
      //code to push page right 20
}
```

**Edit:**

Replace your whole hovering code (from line 200 to line 243) with this. Basically, move it minus to the right when margin is 0, and minus to the left when the margin is not 0. This should solve your problem.

```
$(".show_hide").hover(function() {

    if(parseInt($(".wrapper").css('marginLeft')) == 0) {

        $(".wrapper").animate({
            right: -20,
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);

    } else {

        $(".wrapper").animate({
            left: -20,
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);

    };  

}, function() {

    $(".wrapper").animate({
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        opacity: 1
    }, 300);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried could and this does not work.

Comment: +1, yet I'm not sure whether that is what the OP wants. He really might need to do nothing for a margin of `1px` or negative margins.

Comment: you should be testing 'margin-left' surely, not marginLeft

Comment: using marginLeft and margin-left work in the same way, I have tried both, thanks tho

Comment: @alimac83 in Javascript and jQuery the css properties don't have `-`s. Instead, they start new words with a capital

Comment: Think you still need to remove the px the `.css` adds.: `if (parseInt($('.wrapper').css('marginLeft').replace("px","")) >=  20) { }`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that Brent/11684 - ty :-)

Comment: There is no need to remove the "px" as that's what parseInt() does.

Comment: I forgot to add `left: 0` on hover out. Updated code in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As an update to what Eugene said, you should be able to use this:

```
if (parseInt($('.wrapper').css('margin-left').replace('px', '')) ==  0) {
      //code to push page left 20
}
if (parseInt($('.wrapper').css('margin-left').replace('px', '')) >=  20) {
      //code to push page right 20
}
```

This'll ensure the value returned is an integer and that you're actually getting the value of the left-margin instead of 'marginLeft' which isn't a valid attribute.

EDIT: just noticed I missed a closing bracket but the code works for me. I've made a test on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tCHg6/) (just change the margin-left value to appropriate values to see the box change colour)

Comment: in Javascript and jQuery the css properties don't have -s. Instead, they start new words with a capita

Comment: This does not work, I have updated my code http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~stagedgo/html/ , thanks tho

Comment: It does brent, I just amended the code.. I was missing a bracket :-)

Comment: isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~stagedgo/html , take a look it does not slide right when hovered. I have added the missing bracket as-well.

Comment: So when it slides, then you hover over promotions and it should only slide right by 20 pixels. Then when clicked fully slide right, if that makes sence.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening in both IE and google chrome for me

Comment: http://s8.postimage.org/s0qr2egit/example.png made a image to explain, sorry my english is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// some code here

$('.show_hide').toggle(function(){
  // some code here
},
function() {
  // some code here
});

if ($('.wrapper').css('marginLeft') ==  "0px") {
  $(".show_hide").hover(function () {
    $(".wrapper").animate({ left: 20, opacity : 1 }, 300);
  },
  function () {
    $(".wrapper").animate({ left:0, opacity : 1 }, 300);
  })
}
else if ($('.wrapper').css('marginLeft') > "1px") {
  $(".show_hide").hover(function () {
    $(".wrapper").animate({ right:20, opacity : 1 },300);
  },
  function () {
    $(".wrapper").animate({ right:0, opacity : 1}, 300);    
  })
}           
});
```

What you can see here, is that you define the 'hover' behaviour once when the document is ready.

Whereas what you should do is redefine this behaviour during the 'toggle' event.

I propose you use this code instead:

```
function setupHoverBehaviour() {
  var marginValue = $('.wrapper').css('marginLeft');
  if ( marginValue ==  "auto" || parseInt(marginValue) == "0" ) {
    $(".show_hide").hover(function () {
      $(".wrapper").animate({ left: 20, opacity : 1 }, 300);
    },
    function () {
      $(".wrapper").animate({ left:0, opacity : 1 }, 300);
    })
  }
  else {
    $(".show_hide").hover(function () {
      $(".wrapper").animate({ right:20, opacity : 1 },300);
    },
    function () {
      $(".wrapper").animate({ right:0, opacity : 1}, 300);  
    })
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  // some code here

  $('.show_hide').toggle(function(){
    // some code here

    setupHoverBehaviour();
  },
  function() {
    // some code here

    setupHoverBehaviour();
  });

  setupHoverBehaviour();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the wrapper or the trigger element on the click event to indicate that it had been pushed.  Then you can use .hasClass("pushed") on whichever element to determine if it needs to slide left or right.

Comment: I tried this yesterday with no luck, will try again and update that url.